# callback after ajax form submit rails using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new and quite scared of jquery. I'll get over it soon but what I am trying achieve is that, after a form has been submitted an alert pops up to say it was a success or failiure. I have this working, but it is the ugly alert popup. what I would like is the bootsrap alert notice or alert warning.

My controller is currently looking like this

```
  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subscription.save
        format.html 

        format.js { render :js=>'alert("You have been added to the mailing list");' }
      else
        format.html 
        format.js { render :js=>'alert("You have entered an invalid email address");' }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have bootstrap.js loaded I am just unsure how to implement it.

Comment: You should open modal using jquery `$('#myModal').modal(options);` refer bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your modal, assuming it has an **id "myModalSuccess"**. *You don't need a modal in case of a failure, you just need to render your form and it will display errors for you.* Your controller will look like:

```
def create
  @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @subscription.save
      format.html{redirect_to your_path}
      format.js{}
    else
      format.html{render action: 'new'} 
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can call it inside your **create.js.erb** file like:

```
  $("#myModalSuccess").modal("show");
```

You can also pass other options inside modal method, for details look into [**`bootstraps javascript documentation`**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: what if the validation fails, how do I render the errors?

Comment: @rico_mac for that i think you should simply render your new action. I don't think you need your modal in case of a failure as your form will show up errors anyways. Correcting my answer as well

Comment: yeah i know what you mean. It's just I have a form like this, so i dont think I'd be able to <%= bootstrap_form_for Subscription.new, layout: :inline, url: ' /subscriptions', html: { remote: true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email,  hide_label: :true %>
    <%= f.submit 'Join Mailing List' %>
  <% end %>

Comment: Thanks for your answer though dude. helped.

Comment: @rico_mac you can still render your new action and it'll display validation errors in your form